# Woocommerce how to show products list alphabetically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to list products by alphabetically.Like on my custom template i have listed all products. and there is all letters from a to z in top before listing.Now when user will click on letter b then i need to show products starting with letter b.This is my code to show product listing.

```
global $wpdb,$post;
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$by_letter = array();
while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
 $query->the_post();
 $post->post_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see my working code here http://pastebin.com/jKMJHvjx on this code you can get the product by first letter of alphabet.

I hope this will be helpful for you.